# Datepicker week view

Tags: javascript, html, angular, datepicker

I need a datepicker **(free)** with the **week view**, something like:

[image]

I found [this](https://demo.mobiscroll.com/fullscreen/calendar/week-view), more is paid!

**Preferably javascript, angular, html**

Answer (score 2):

It's easy make yourself. Make a function that have as argument: week, day of week (0 to 6), month and year

As the first day of a month can be Monday, Thursday... You must to calculate a "increment" depending the month and year you choose, and pass as argument to the function too

```
private getIncrement(year:number,month:number): number{
    const date = new Date('' + year + '-' + month + '-1');
    const increment = date.getDay() > 0 ? date.getDay() - 2 : 5;
    return increment;
}

private getDate(week: number, dayWeek: number, 
                 year:number,month:number,increment:number) {
    let date:any
    const day = week * 7 + dayWeek - increment;

    if (day <= 0) {
        const fechaAuxiliar = new Date('' + year + '-' + month + '-1');
        date = new Date(fechaAuxiliar.getTime() + ((day - 1) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    }
    else {
        date = new Date('' + year + '-' + month + '-' + day);

        if (isNaN(date.getTime())) {
            let fechaAuxiliar = new Date('' + year + '-' + month + '-1');
            date = new Date(fechaAuxiliar.getTime() + ((day + 1 - increment) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
     }
   }
     return date;
}
```

After all, you make a *ngFor, add two buttons and enjoy code!

Comment: Thanks for your response, it was the base for implementing my own lib: https://github.com/FranclisJunior/datepicker-week-view

Answer (score 0):

[Material 2](http://material.angular.io) has a great date picker thats free and easy to use

[ng2-date-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-date-picker) also would seem to have the specifics you are after

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need it to be specifically in the weekview as in the picture above

Comment: You can customize, not everything will be on a platter for you to consume, you also need to sometimes create

Comment: I followed your advice and implemented my own lib: https://github.com/FranclisJunior/datepicker-week-view